# Forked tongue and silver tongue mean the same thing?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between Forked tongue and silver tongue person?

Comment: Related: [Why “silver-tongued” for someone who is convincing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/357639), [Speaking with a forked tongue](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31172)

Answer (score 1):

A person who speaks with a forked tongue is a liar or hypocrite; a person who has a silver tongue is good at persuading people.

> forked tongue noun
> UK
>
> speak with a forked tongue ​
>
> to tell lies or say one thing and mean something
> else

[Forked tongue](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forked-tongue)

> silver-tongued adjective UK
>
> literary
>
> If you are silver-tongued, you are good at persuading
> people to do things.

[Silver-tongued](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/silver-tongued)